# Debian installation not booting after Nvidia drivers installation

Tags: debian, nvidia

I recently moved my Debian Gnome 3 installation to a new computer with a GTX 1070.  I had previously installed old Nvidia drivers which didn't support the 1070, so when I booted up I was faced with a blinking prompt.  To remedy this, I went into the command prompt with CTRL-ALT-F2, did `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and installed the  [Nvidia 367.27 Drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverresults.aspx/104284/en-us).

When I rebooted after installing the drivers successfully, Debian displayed "Loading, please wait...", indefinitely.  When I rebooted again, it (Gnome, I presume) displayed [this](http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/15/1018/h_1445153792_7546686_5272ea6b53.png) "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." message.  Now, when I boot into Debian, I always get one of those two messages.

Does anyone have a clue what has gone wrong? Is there any way to fix this, or is it time for me to reinstall?

Comment: When you get the "Oh No!"-message, can you switch to a terminal prompt?

Comment: @Fiximan Yes.  When I log in on the terminal prompt, I get the message `systemd-logind[1814]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service` (after that message I can still type commands into the prompt)

Comment: First of all, I'd suggest installing the driver from the Debian repository, read these two pages on [how](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_8_.22Jessie.22) and [why](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian). This usually should fix your problem, but use an older driver - usually things should work as before then. Note that the latest driver is not always necessary.

Comment: @Fiximan can't install the drivers from the Debian repository because they don't support the GTX 1070.  Before I tried installing the new drivers, I had the old drivers from the Debian repository, and all I got was a blinking prompt

Comment: Merge your accounts, don't reregister for everything.